# Finding partial duplicates in perl

Tags: perl, duplicates, partial

So after months of trying and failing and being generally stuck, I finally decided to go out and seek outside help. I am still learning new tricks in perl and hope someone here may be able to help me out, so without further ado...

I have species in the format of:

```
>gi|###|...|...|...[species name] amino acid sequence
```

Of these lines, i will have some that contain the same species name (like Homo Sapiens), but different amino acid sequence. This is why i cannot remove duplicates by hash or other means, since technically they are not exact duplicates.

I need a way to remove or not print the duplicate species name but have my output file contain the format specified above. So if I had 3 occurrences of Homo Sapiens with different amino sequences or #'s, i need my output to contain only one Homo Sapiens (doesn't matter which, can be random) with its corresponding sequence.

Any help or point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated! Hope i was clear enough on the question. Thanks for the read! :D

Comment: Umm, use a hash with the species name as key? Could you explain how this does not work for you?

Comment: Why not store `species` as your key and populate an array with your sequence values and then output as you expect? `my %h; while (<>) { push @{$h{$1}}, $2 if /\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)/; }`

Comment: It was my understanding that the hash was more specific, and so it would not be able to separate partial differences...
Also since i need the entire species name with its corresponding sequence, it wouldn't detect a duplicate since the sequences were different even though the species name were the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can use a hash. Just gotta use the right key.

```
my %seen;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\|/;
    my ($species) = $fields[4] =~ /\[([^\]]+)\]/ or die;
    print "$_\n" if !$seen{$species}++;
}
```

Example input:

```
>gi|###|[1](A)
>gi|###|[2](B)
>gi|###|[1](C)
>gi|###|[1](D)
>gi|###|[2](E)
>gi|###|[3](F)
>gi|###|[3](F)
```

Output:

```
>gi|###|[1](A)
>gi|###|[2](B)
>gi|###|[3](F)
```

Comment: So $species would be just my species name which would be seen in the hash which is found in my data file? Would this also give me the species name + its corresponding sequence? Thank you for your input, haven't gotten it to work but will keep tinkering.

Comment: Trying to figure out why it's not giving me the output...
I'm using perl 5.10.0

Comment: What are you talking about? It's impossible for it to give no output if you give it any input at all.

Comment: That's the weird part, keeps dying in the while <input> part

Here's an example of the input:
>gi|45439306|ref|NP_001340.2| aspartate--tRNA ligase, cytoplasmic [Homo sapiens]
MPSASASRKSQEKPREIMDAAEDYAKERYGISSMIQSQEKPDRVLVRVRDLTIQKADEVVWVRARVHTSR

Comment: That's not the format you specified, and I was missing a `+`. Adjusted and fixed.

Comment: Oh i get it, thanks kindly! Have to be very specific with these things ^_^